# Optimise Search within the QGIS API

Tags: qgis, python, loop

I would like to ask you about the following code, it works, but I don't think is very helpful to have elif, elif,elif... always. Then, I have to optimise it. The problem is that I can't access to features in every string of each dir() (or don't know how to do it)

> ```
> def search(your_search):
>
> dir(iface)
> dir(qgis.core) 
> dir(qgis.gui) 
>   '''
>    i = 0
>    list_iface = dir(iface)
>    list_core = dir(qgis.core)
>    list_gui = dir(qgis.gui)
>
>   #while your_search not in list_iface, ?? oh no...
>    '''
>     if your_search in dir(iface):
>      print '\n'
>      print "THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN iface API"
>     elif your_search in dir(qgis.core):
>      print '\n'
>      print "THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN qgis.core API"
>     elif your_search in dir(qgis.gui):
>      print '\n'
>      print "THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN qgis.gui API"
>     else:
>         print '\n'
>         print "IS NOT IN THESE THREE APIs"
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `elif` you could use a dictionary with the paths as keys and the strings you want to print as values, for example:

```
results = {
    dir(iface): "THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN iface API",
    dir(qgis.core):"THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN qgis.core API",
    dir(qgis.gui): "THE CLASS/FUNCTION/METHOD ", "'",your_search,"'", " IS IN qgis.gui API"
}
for key in results.keys():
    if your_search in key:
        print "\n"
        print results[key]
    else:
        print "IS NOT IN THESE THREE APIs"
```

Comment: aaah that is what I haven't tried... using a dictionary. I thought in using a tuple because it is only for reading, thus, it iterates faster. Well, dictionary makes this easier. 

Thank you very much